# CastError with GET endpoint but not with POST endpoint in Express / Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm testing an endpoint that gets user data from ids, using a mongoose query. My code works like intended for a POST endpoint, but returns a strange error if the endpoint is changed to GET.

```
router.route("/test").get(async (req, res) => { // works for POST route and request, not GET
  const ids = req.body.ids;
  users = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    const userData = await User.findById(ids[i]);
    users.push(userData);
  }
  res.json(users);
});
```

With the above code, I get this error: "Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "test" at path "_id" for model "Group""

Replacing the request type with POST, I get my desired result. Why is this the case, when the rest of the code is the same?

Comment: Please show both HTTP requests you make (GET and POST)

Answer (score 0):

**Dont make endpoint a little bit similar**

example :

```
product/:id

and similar with

item/:id
```

**Make your endpoint unique**

```
product/:id_product

item/:id_item
```

**The core is, check your endpoint and make unique!**

The example above is a case that I encountered